# update datagridview in mainform after closing addnewline form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, datagridview, refresh

I have a datagridview of a client list in my main form. I have an add button that opens a new form with a design to add new data. After saving the data and closing the form, the datagridview in the main form doesn't update.
I've checked the internet and i can't really find anything usefull for my purposes.
Is there like a "on close childform parentform datagridview.refresh i can execute?

I've checked other similar questions but i can't seem to find an answer that suits this "environment"

thank you in advance, i'm a beginner

Comment: There a a ton of different strategies for this.  Which one is the right one to use really depends on your data sources for your various controls in the forms, how you've bound your data and how you're calling the second form as to which one is going to work best for you in your situation

Answer (score 1):

This problem crops up all the time and I'm fairly certain that you are making the same mistake that everyone else does. When you use a data adapter or table adapter to populate a `DataTable` and then bind that to the `DataGridView` in your main form, there is no direct connection to the database. That `DataTable` is a local copy of the data in the database at the time of the query. If you make changes to the database later, the `DataTable` knows nothing about that so it doesn't reflect those changes. Why would it? There are two solutions to this: the bad one and the good one.

The bad solution is to requery the database after making the change. That will refresh your local copy of the data to the current state of the database. It would be up to you whether to discard everything you have and get everything again or to only get the changes and merge those into the data you already have.

The good solution is to do things the other way around. That means that your second form doesn't make any changes to the database so there's nothing to retrieve. When the user confirms saving the new record from the second form, it doesn't connect to the database at all but, instead, simply returns the data to the main form. The main form adds a new row to the `DataTable` so that change is immediately reflected in the `DataGridView`. You then use the same data adapter or table adapter that populated the `DataTable` in the first place to save the changes back to the database by calling `Update` instead of `Fill`. That will save all changes in a single batch so you can do it multiple times to save changes one by one or let the user make multiple changes first and then save the lot in one go at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The key point of this question is the update of the data source.
Generally, this operation is performed by connecting to the database. My example uses the Microsoft SQL Server.

The default permission of the control is Friend. So you can write a class to access `Form1.DataGridView1` and bind the data source of `DataGridView1`. Calling this class in Form2 allows you to refresh the data source of Form1.DataGridView.

Right Click Project=>Add=>New item=>Class File

RefershDgr.vb

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class RefershDgr
Shared Sub LoadData()
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("My Server info ")
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from ClientInfo", connection)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(dt)
    Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
End Class
```

Form1.vb:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    RefershDgr.LoadData()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim form As New Form2()
    form.Show()
End Sub
End Class
```

Form2.vb:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim name As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim age As String = CUInt(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim email As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("My Server info")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand("insert into ClientInfo values('" + name + "','" + age + "','" + email + "')", connection)
    connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
    RefershDgr.LoadData()
    MsgBox("insert success")
End Sub
End Class
```

Result:
[image]